# Regex In notepad ++ how do I add prefix 0x to everything after the =

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this so far: find `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})` and replace with `,0x\1`, but this adds `0x` in front every 2 chars with match expression. How can I only apply this `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})` after the `=`

Exmaple:

```
TV = 0xB11BAB56 
CAT = 0x9D3DCB7A
```

What I need:

```
TV = 0xB1, 0x1B, 0xAB, 0x56
CAT = 0x9D, 0x3D, 0xCB, 0x7A
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, I'd use something like replace `= 0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})` with `= 0x\1, 0x\2, 0x\3, 0x\4`